# Qt Creator fails in designer tab

Tags: kubuntu, qt, qt-creator, plasma, plasma-5

Qt Creator in designer tab displays black frames.[image]

At the same time in Konsole I have the following message several times (more than 30 times):

```
QQuickWidget cannot be used as a native child widget. Consider setting Qt::AA_DontCreateNativeWidgetSiblings
```

I tried to find the solution in Internet, but, unfortunately they don't work. How can it be fixed?

P.S.: Kubuntu 15.04, Qt 5.5.0, NVidia drivers 346.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem on 15.04 with Qt 5.4, and Intel integrated graphics. I found this workaround to get it running, from the command line:

```
KDE_FULL_SESSION= XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP= qtcreator
```

In my case, I installed from the download tool from the Qt website, so I had to modify the command to point to my Qt Creator binary. Mine installed to /opt/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator, so I dropped that whole path into the XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP part.

Source: [Qt Bug Report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-46919)